# Different access modifiers of properties in C#

Tags: c#, getter-setter, access-modifiers

Can we have different access modifier for `get` and `set` in a property?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can, however it is subject to the rule that your getter/setter cannot have a less restricted access modifier than the property itself.

For example (C#):

```
public Foo { get; private set; } //this is okay
protected Bar { get; public set; } //this will throw a compile error
```

Answer (score 4):

You can restrict the getter or setter of a property:

```
public string MyProperty
{
    get { return _myProperty; }
    private set { _myProperty = value; }
}
```

It also works with internal and protected. **However**, the key word here is "restrict" - you can't make either modifier more accessible than the overall modifier.

Comment: Technically you could have a private getter with a public setter instead.  Any way you do it, you can have different modifiers for get or set.

Comment: @light yes, however there are some situations that are not allowed; see my answer below.

Comment: @Brian sorry, I didn't take that into account with my answer.  You are completely correct.